# AnimationGroup Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

**Demo：**

```
__block NSMutableArray *animaArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];

for ( int i = 3 ; i > 0 ; i-- ) {
        CAKeyframeAnimation *anima1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        NSValue *value0 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30,40)];
        NSValue *value1 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50,60)];
        anima1.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:value0,value1, nil];
        [animaArr addObject:anima1.values];
    }  

CAAnimationGroup *groupAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
groupAnimation.animations = animaArr;
groupAnimation.duration = 5;
[_movingChipImgView.layer addAnimation:groupAnimation forKey:nil];
```

**crash information:**

> 2016-12-20 20:16:09.876 Pok[1781:474428] -[__NSArrayI setDefaultDuration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000022d9e0

Comment: I'm not familiar with CAAnimation, but my guess is that `animaArr` is a array of array of animations, and not an array of animations: `groupAnimation.animations` is waiting for `NSArray<CAAnimation *>`, but doesn't seems the case, and that could explains your error maybe.

Comment: you are right. the solution:

Comment: [animaArr addObject:anima1.values];->[animaArr addObject:anima1];